# How to render dropdown based on an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have a `contacts` variable that is set by calling an API. This is all done in an immediately invoked function expression `(async () => {})();`. I have to get a token to access the Microsoft Graph API. This lets me call an read the selected email using the Office.js library `await getMessage(microsoftGraphAccessToken...)`.

I call my own API endpoint `getContactsByEmail`. The `contacts` variable contains data, but the `contactDropdown` does not show - it just remains as `<></>`.

```
const App = () => {
  let contacts = null;
  let contactDropdown = <></>;

  (async () => {
    let microsoftGraphAccessToken = null;
    let message = null;

    await Office.onReady();

    //Check if Graph is already authorized
    const graphTokenResponse = await graphAuth.getToken(graphLoginRequest);

    microsoftGraphAccessToken = graphTokenResponse.accessToken;

    await getMessage(microsoftGraphAccessToken, Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId, async (data) => {
      message = data;
    });

    const contacts = await getContactsByEmail(message.from.emailAddress.address);

    if (contacts.length > 0) {
      contactDropdown = (
        <select>
          {contacts.map((contact) => (
            <option key={contact.id} value={contact.id}>
              {contact.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      );
    }
  })();

  return (
    <div>
      {contactDropdown}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is not the way you should be using react at all to do something like this... Have you considered how you have used the "contacts" variable(s) and the contactDropdown variable? You have defined it in such a way that it will never render out a map because it will always identify it as being empty to begin with. You desperately need to be using react hooks. You will  need both the useEffect hook as well as the useState hook, without either of those it is worthless and not react-like... This is a  good way to make a million api call's for the same garbage...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In whatever React tutorial(s) you're using, you've overlooked the single most fundamental concept in React... *state*.

The initial value for the variable `contactDropdown` is `<></>`.  So that's what gets rendered in the component when it first renders.  Then at a later time you update the value for that variable.  However, directly updating a variable does not trigger React to re-render the component.  Updating *state* does.

Put the variable in state:

```
const [contactDropdown, setContactDropdown] = useState(<></>);
```

Then use the state setter when you need to update it at a later time:

```
if (contacts.length > 0) {
  setContactDropdown(
    <select>
      {contacts.map((contact) => (
        <option key={contact.id} value={contact.id}>
          {contact.name}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

Invoking that state setter function tells React to queue a re-render after updating the state value.

---

As an aside... *In general* it's uncommon to store *markup* in state.  Instead, you should store *data* in state and generate the markup in the rendering.  What you have should work, but could easily run into problems if you ever need to do anything else with that data.

For example, store the "contacts" in state:

```
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
```

And update it with your fetched data:

```
const newContacts = await getContactsByEmail(message.from.emailAddress.address);
setContacts(newContacts);
```

Then use that *data* to render the markup in your component:

```
return (
  <div>
    {contacts.length > 0 ? (
      <select>
        {contacts.map((contact) => (
          <option key={contact.id} value={contact.id}>
            {contact.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    ) : <></>}
  </div>
);
```

---

Additionally, **and this is important**... I just realized your component will *infinitely* re-render.  Don't make API calls like that directly in the component body.  They'll be invoked on every render.  And if that operation itself triggers a re-render, then every render will trigger a re-render.

To perform an API call once when the component first renders, wrap it in `useEffect` with an empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // your IIFE goes here
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help @David. I moved `contacts` to a state variable. I converted my IIFE to a function and I am now using that inside `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  initialize();
})();

const initialize = () => {
    let microsoftGraphAccessToken = null;
    let message = null;

    await Office.onReady();

    //Check if Graph is already authorized
    const graphTokenResponse = await graphAuth.getToken(graphLoginRequest);

    microsoftGraphAccessToken = graphTokenResponse.accessToken;

    await getMessage(microsoftGraphAccessToken, Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId, async (data) => {
      message = data;
    });

    const contacts = await getContactsByEmail(message.from.emailAddress.address);

    if (contacts.length > 0) {
      contactDropdown = (
        <select>
          {contacts.map((contact) => (
            <option key={contact.id} value={contact.id}>
              {contact.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      );
    }
};
```

The issue I was having is I was rendering an element from a variable: `let contactDropdown = <></>;` but I am now directly rendering it.

```
return (
    <div>
      {contacts.length > 0 ? (
        <div>
          <label id={contactDropdownId}>Select a Contact</label>
          <select>
            {contacts.map((contact) => (
              <option key={contact.id} value={contact.id}>
                {contact.name}
              </option >
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
    </div>
)
```

I was wondering if there was a reason for this though? Maybe I am misunderstanding the point in time when `contactDropdown` is being rendered.